# 'unzip' a Vec of tuples

Tags: sorting, vector, rust, idioms

So if I've got two vectors:

```rs
let mut vec1 = vec![true, false, false, true];
let mut vec2 = vec![1.0, 0.0, 4.0, 2.0];
```

and I want to sort `vec1` and `vec2` together according to the floats in `vec2`, I can zip them together into a tuple and the sort the zipped vector of tuples:

```rs
let zipped = vec1.iter().zip(vec2.iter()).collect::<(bool, f64)>();
zipped.sort_by(|a, b| a.1.partial_cmp(&b.1).expect("Can't compare"));
```

And then I can re-assign the values back to the vectors

```rs
vec1 = zipped.iter().map(|z| z.0).collect();
vec2 = zipped.iter().map(|z| z.1).collect();
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of sorting two parallel vectors in rust? This seems really verbose.

I could put the two items in a struct, but the sorting value is more throw-away than I'd like to associate with a struct all the time, and I feel like creating a wrapper struct to contain the sorting value + original struct is not going to make things any more simple.

[Link to playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2dd496c58da41aa383c1728511cf717d), Full code:

```rs
fn main() {
    let mut vec1: Vec<bool> = vec![true, false, false, true];
    let mut vec2: Vec<f64> = vec![1.0, 0.0, 4.0, 2.0];
    println!("vec1: {:?}", vec1); // => vec1: [true, false, false, true]
    println!("vec2: {:?}", vec2); // => vec2: [1.0, 0.0, 4.0, 2.0]
    
    let mut zipped = vec1
        .into_iter()
        .zip(vec2.into_iter())
        .collect::<Vec<(bool, f64)>>();
        
    zipped.sort_by(|a, b| a.1.partial_cmp(&b.1).expect("Can't compare"));

    let vec1_sorted: Vec<bool> = zipped.iter().map(|z| z.0).collect();
    let vec2_sorted: Vec<f64> = zipped.iter().map(|z| z.1).collect();
    println!("vec1_sorted: {:?}", vec1_sorted); // => vec1_sorted: [false, true, true, false]
    println!("vec2_sorted: {:?}", vec2_sorted); // =>  vec2_sorted: [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0]
}
```

Comment: Also (more exact duplicate, but answers the question worse): [Rust: Given vector of tuples create two separate lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69439298/rust-given-vector-of-tuples-create-two-separate-lists/69439348#69439348)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`Iterator::unzip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.unzip):

```rust
let (vec1_sorted, vec2_sorted): (Vec<bool>, Vec<f64>) = zipped.into_iter().unzip();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6898befac75f9d5f2e64ed60c2ec948b)

Comment: Thanks, I'm feeling silly now. I see the `Iterator::zip` docs don't mention `unzip` (although `unzip` does mention `zip`). To suggest a docs edit would I submit a pull request to https://github.com/rust-lang/rust or is there a better way?

Comment: @beyarkay Just file a PR. Small changes like that don't even require FCP.

Comment: [Here's the PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/96038), for future travellers.

Answer (score 1):

You have [`Iterator::unzip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.unzip) exactly for this purpose:

```rust
(vec1, vec2) = zipped.into_iter().unzip();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e903b4126ef8de9fca8b040a16ea04dd).